# macbook can not hibernate while connected to external monitor

Tags: macbook, hibernate

I have a late 2008 macbook pro unibody 15. I use it with an external monitor. Before upgrading to leopard, I used the widget "deep sleep" to put it into hibernation mode. Now I updated to snow leopard, and when using the external monitor, it does not work, only works without the monitor connected, anybody can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread on macrumors seems to address the same issue but with Lion:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1124768

Can you just use the keyboard shortcut to put it to sleep? The keyboard combo seems to be:
"Command + Option then hold Eject"

Does this help?  This doesn't use your widget, but it seems quite simple (only takes a couple seconds).

EDIT: I found [this link](http://mac.bigresource.com/Track/mac-O4l6fjHJU/) where they turned off the setting to ask for a password on wake-up. It's worth a try...